# Structure of endgame tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I think as the number of questions grows, we should divide up the [endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endgame) tag according to material (but keep [endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endgame) as a top level tag).

What is the best way to do this? Introduce new tags [rook-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rook-endgame), [knight-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knight-endgame) and so on or use the existing [endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endgame)[rooks](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooks), [endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endgame)[knights](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights)?

Comment: 3 upvotes  and no one says no so far, go for it

Answer (score 2):

I definitely think that the more specific the tags, the better.  The one catch is that we should probably keep the more general tags as well until they become unwieldy.

There's a limit of 5 tags per question - those should be the best 5 tags for a question.  So if a question has 4 tags, feel free to add [rook-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rook-endgame) as an example.  However, if it has 5 good tags already, then probably leave it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that new tags should arise "naturally". The other way to do it is to make sure every question has minimum e.g. 3 tags and maximum e.g. 5 tags. Then, new tags will definitely arise.

Regarding endgames, I think that the search engines on- and off-site will pick up a separate tag setup "knight" and "endgame". I am not a big fan of "knight-endgame" and similar tags. What is a knight endgame, is it a knight versus knight? How about knight versus three pawns? I vote for separate tags. Cheers.